# RabbitMQ / MQTT performance

Tags: tcp, rabbitmq, mqtt

We are using RabbitMQ/with MQTT adapter as a broker to connect nodes for monitoring.

Theoretically, being TCP based we can have a max of N connections/interface, as having N port, where N ~ [5000, 65000]. I also realize that by having multiple network interfaces, I can theoretically service far more number of connections.

Is there a sensible limit to the max number of connections and hence the number of nodes that can be serviced having a sane CPU/MEM usage pattern.

But, it would also mean maintaining & processing N connections concurrently on commodity HW (QuadCore 2GHz/8GB RAM). Is there any:

1. Formal process to derive how many connections can be serviced.
2. What would be the system/rabbitmq parameters that I should be look at to optimize.
3. It would indicate that it is also goverened by the daemon servicing the connections. Any formal architecture / design constraints (though at the moment we are sticking to RabbitMQ).

Currently, 30000 connections are possible to be serviced with below config, but with %cpu ~ 100% and memory almost getting exhausted > 60% with a throughput of ~ 80 (x300bytes) messages/sec.

```
HW: i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz/4 cores/2 threads & 8GB RAM.
SW: Ubuntu/RabbitMQ with MQTT adapter.

**rabbitmq.config**
[
{rabbit, 
    [
        {tcp_listeners,    [5672]}, 
        {loopback_users, []},
        {vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.8},
        {vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio, 0.75}
    ]
},
{rabbitmq_mqtt, [{default_user,     <<"guest">>},
    {default_pass,     <<"guest">>},
    {allow_anonymous,  true},
    {vhost,            <<"/">>},
    {exchange,         <<"amq.topic">>},
    {subscription_ttl, 1800000},
    {prefetch,         10},
    {ssl_listeners,    []},
    {tcp_listeners,    [1883]},
    {tcp_listen_options, [binary,
        {packet,    raw},
        {reuseaddr, true},
        {backlog,   128},
        {nodelay,   true}]}]}].
```

Also, is it feasible to retire/evict connections while handing new connections based on a policy like LRU / LFU of cache-eviction. Can this be done at the system level (OS / TCP layer).

Thanks.JB.